# Kivy, TextInput with plain black borders

Tags: kivy

I'm trying simply to create a plain border with TextInput like the image below:
[image: Black border image]

```
TextInput:
   size_hint_y: None
   height: 122
   disabled_background_color: 1,1,1,1
   disabled_foreground_color: 1,1,1,1
   background_disabled_normal: ''
   background_normal: ''
   background_color: 1,1,1,1
   foreground_color: 0,0,0,1
```

I did try any number of combinations of the code above, including disabling them. If I don't disable background_normal, it shows up as very light black to white gradient. I just want simple black borders around my TextInput.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that using `border` and `BorderImage` would be the way to do this, but I couldn't figure it out. Here is way that over rides the default `TextInput` style:

```
# over ride the default TextInput style
<-TextInput>:
    canvas.before:
        # Draw border first
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

        # Draw background (covers most of the above border)
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        Rectangle:
            size: (self.width - self.border[1] - self.border[3], self.height - self.border[0] - self.border[2])
            pos: (self.x + self.border[3], self.y + self.border[0])

        # set the color for the text
        Color:
            rgba: self.foreground_color
```

This still uses the `background_color` and `foreground_color`, but the border color is hard coded as `0,0,0,1`. The `border` property of the `TextInput` sets the width of the border as specified in the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.border)

Note that the `-` in the rule means to ignore any previous rules.

Just add this before you use a `TextInput` in your `kv` file.